is there a common pattern in rust to define structs that don't care if they own or borrow a certain value?
This question isn't about a specific situation that I need help with, but about a more generic problem, that I've stumbled upon many in many domains while programming in Rust. Due to the generality of the problems, some of the examples may seem rather contrived, but I'll try my best to provide enough context to make the problem understandable.
Let's say I have some struct Foo that has some purpose and to fulfill that purpose the Foo needs access to a &Bar. So for simplicity, let's define it like this for now:
struct Foo<'a> {
  bar: &'a Bar,
}

impl Foo<'_> {
  fn fulfill_purpose(&self) {
    let bar = self.bar;
    // We have access to a &Bar \o/
  }
}

Now there are several contexts, where Foo might be used and in each context there might be different ways on how we get access to a Bar. For example, me might already own a Bar on the stack or similar, so we can just construct our Foo like this:
let bar = construct_bar();
let foo = Foo { bar: &bar };
// We now have a `Foo` that can live as long as `bar` lives \o/

But in another case, we might want to serialize a Bar from {disk, network, whatever...} and construct a Foo. If we also want to encapsulate this whole process in a utility function, we're out of luck with our current definition:
fn fetch_foo() -> Foo {
  let bar = fetch_bar();
  let foo = Foo { bar };
  // Oops! We can't return foo now, because it refers to bar which only lives for the scope of this function
}

We could make this situation easier by changing the definition of Foo to own the Bar instead of borrowing it. But that makes other situation harder, for example we might want to avoid copying a Bar if we want to share it between multiple Foos or we might have a global Bar in a static behind a Mutex that can be used:
static GLOBAL_BAR: Mutex<Bar>;

fn global_foo() -> Foo {
  let bar = GLOBAL_BAR.lock();
  let foo = Foo { bar: &bar };
  // Oops! We can't return foo now, because the `MutexGuard` in `bar` we're borrowing from only lives for the scope of this function
}

So neither Foo owning a Bar nor borrowing a reference of it can satisfy all three of these cases. So maybe we can do some generic magic to satisfy them all? Let's try:
struct Foo<SomeBar> {
  bar: SomeBar,
}

impl<SomeBar: SomeTrait> Foo<SomeBar> {
  fn fulfill_purpose(&self) {
    // Assuming SomeBar::as_bar(&self) -> &Bar
    let bar = self.bar.as_bar()
    // We have access to a &Bar \o/
  }
}

This seems promising. As long as Bar: SomeBar, &Bar: SomeBar and MutexGuard<Bar>: SomeBar all hold, we can successfully implement all three examples above. The only question remaining is what trait to use in place of SomeBar. The standard library already has several traits that might fit, but they all don't seem to do the trick properly:

Deref and AsRef both provide methods (deref and as_ref) that could take the place of our SomeBar::as_bar, but there are not blanket implementations for Deref<T> for T or AsRef<T> for T, so it doesn't work for our case where we want the Bar to be owned by Foo.

Borrow seems like it was deliberately made for this case. It does exactly what we want and even has a blanket implementation for Borrow<T> for T. However, Borrow seems to be very unpopular and some types from std (e.g. std::cell::Ref) don't even implement it. So while this works for all three examples above, it would be very likely to stumble across a case where it doesn't anymore, because some type forgot to implement Borrow.


The closest I came to finding a general solution to this problems was to define a helper newtype like this
struct Owned<T>(T);

impl<T> Deref for Owned<T> {
  type Target = T;

  fn deref(&self) -> Self::Target {
    &self.0
  }
}

and then define Foo like this
struct Foo<SomeBar: Deref<Target=Bar>> {
  bar: SomeBar,
}

However, I've never seen this approach used in any code I've encountered. So now I'm wondering if I've made some fundamental mistake in my approach to this kind of problem. Is there any common solution for this problem? Am I making some other fundamental mistake to stumble over this problem so often in the first place?
This question is similar to Rust generic type that can either own or borrow its content but the answer to that question suggests to use Cow, which tracks if something is borrowed or owned at runtime, whereas I would like a solution where the ownership of values is statically tracked through generics.

I think you're right that this is really what Borrow is for, and the missing impls appear to be an oversight (albeit there are some issues).  I suppose you could define your own version of the trait and implement it for the stdlib types.

Use Borrow, or create your own trait like Borrow that covers all of the types you need.

Answering literally the question in title - no, it's not common at all: sometimes you're fully generic (like Vec and similar), sometimes you know whether you have something with lifetime or something 'static, but the middleground is niche. Ownership trees is a quite fundamental part of architecture of Rust programs, after all.
